# Firebase Image Storage - Load thumbnail before original image from Firebase Realtime Database + Storage

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I have Picasso in my android app, so i can retrieve the image URL from firebase database+storage to my recyclerview and show it. now, i have make thumbnails of all firebase storage image. 
Now i want to load thumbnails before original image. the image name starting like - 502.jpg and thumbnails are starting from thumb_502.jpg.
[Like this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANyzV.jpg)

ImageAdapter Class

```
 public class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ImageViewHolder> {
private Context mContext;
private List<Upload> mUploads;

private OnItemClickListener mListener;

public ImageAdapter(Context context, List<Upload> uploads) {
    mContext = context;
    mUploads = uploads;
}

@Override
public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.image_item, parent, false);
    return new ImageViewHolder(v);
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Upload uploadCurrent = mUploads.get(position);

    String imgUrl = uploadCurrent.getImageUrl();
    String thUrl = uploadCurrent.getThumbUrl();
    holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    if( imgUrl != null && !"".equals(imgUrl) ){

    Picasso.with(mContext)
            .load(uploadCurrent.getThumbUrl())
            .into(holder.imageView, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    Picasso.with(mContext)
                            .load(uploadCurrent.getImageUrl())
                            .into(holder.imageView);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {

                }
            });}

}
```

Upload class

```
public class Upload {
    public class Upload {
private String mImageUrl;
private String mThumbUrl;
private String mKey;


public Upload() {
    //empty constructor needed
}
public Upload(String imageUrl) {
      mImageUrl = imageUrl;

}

public String getImageUrl() {
    return mImageUrl;
}

public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
    mImageUrl = imageUrl;
}

public String getThumbUrl() {
    return mThumbUrl;
}

public void setThumbUrl(String thumbUrl) {
    mThumbUrl = thumbUrl;
}

@Exclude
public String getKey(){
    return mKey;
}
@Exclude
public void setKey(String key){
    mKey = key;
}
```

}

ImageActivity class

```
public class ImageActivity1 extends AppCompatActivity implements ImageAdapter.OnItemClickListener{

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private ImageAdapter mAdapter;

private ProgressBar mProgressCircle;
private FirebaseStorage mStorage;
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;
private ValueEventListener mDBListener;
private List<Upload> mUploads;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image1);
    Intent cIntent = getIntent();
    final String categoryIntent = String.valueOf(cIntent.getStringExtra("category"));
    Toast.makeText(ImageActivity1.this,categoryIntent,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    //mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    //mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),3);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);

    mProgressCircle = findViewById(R.id.progress_circle);

    mUploads = new ArrayList<>();

    mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(ImageActivity1.this, mUploads);

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(ImageActivity1.this);
    ////////////////////
    mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

    mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");

    mDBListener = mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mUploads.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Upload upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                upload.setKey(postSnapshot.getKey());
                mUploads.add(upload);
            }

            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

           mProgressCircle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(ImageActivity1.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mProgressCircle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: i want to load thumbnails before original image

Comment: @MTTApps you have thumbnail available in Storage ?

Comment: @Ashish Yes, i create it using by firebase functions

Comment: @MTTApps i am asking when you try to load data from Firebase storage the same amount of time required for Load the main image. Better use Loading drawable.

Comment: Or you can try something like this `Glide.with(context)
    .load(URL)
    .thumbnail(0.1f)
    .into(image_view)`